# How to find changes to a section of code

Tags: mercurial

So there is a bug in a bit of code I wrote a long while back. When I went to look into it, it had all been changed! I don't know which colleague changed it. I don't know when it was changed. This file has been changed many, many times. I'm not concerned with everytime this file has a commit. I definitely don't want too look through all 100 commits this file has been in just to find which commits changed this area of code.

I want to find all of the commits that affected file xyz.txt between lines 250 and 300.

Better yet, I want to find all of the commits that affected the function doStuff() in file xyz.txt.

Is that possible?

Comment: Try `git bisect`.

Comment: I accidentally added the git tag. I'm using mercurial. If it isn't possible in mercurial, I'll switch VCS.

Comment: Mercurial and Git are pretty equal in capabilities, and sometimes even use the same command names. In this case, the commands are `hg blame` and `hg bisect` which correspond to `git blame` and `git bisect` (though the usages are a little bit different).

Answer (score 0):

As torek said, hg blame will do the job.
To filter lines between 250 and 300 you could do:

```
hg blame -ucd xyz.txt | cat -n | sed -n 250,300p
```

-u: Show user

-c: Show changeset

-d: Show date